# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working in staticTableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

hello I have a `TableViewController` in my storyboard with static cells. I want to launch different view controller or trigger some methods on each cell clicked. if I drag the segue from my `cell` to another ViewController it doesn't work and also `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` also not working.

here is my class

```
class ProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        let row = indexPath.row
        print("Row: \(row)") //nothing is printing out

}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     print("hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: In the storyboard, are you sure the TableViewController is assigned to be of ProfileTableViewController class?

Comment: @jbcd13 I am not getting any errors

Comment: @bearMountain 100% sure

Comment: Have you set ProfileTableViewController as UITableViewController delegate?

Comment: Do you just want to deselect the row in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @Raz no.No I didn't. Its already set when you drag the tableviewcontroller on storyboard

Comment: @ShehzadAli didn't get you

Comment: In your method didSelectRowAtIndexPath you have just deselected the row. You aren't doing anything else. Selection for row can be set as none in attribute inspector after selecting cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding the `TableView` in `Storyboard`, make sure that when you right click the `TableView`, that the `UIViewController` which holds the `TableView` is set as its delegate, or any other object which seems proper for your task.

[image: Validating dataSource and delegate]